# Get (A < B) when only '>' operator is overloaded

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

My code is using a complex data structure, and operator overloading is done to help me sort the data.

In another use case, a check of A > B is needed so operator overloading is first implemented for '>' operator. Now the current use case needs to check A < B.

How do I get '<' by using only '>'?

This is the equation that I got:

```
A < B = !(A > B) && !(A == B)
      = !(A > B) && !((A <= B) && (B <= A))
      = !(A > B) && (!(A <= B) || !(B <= A))
      = !(A > B) && ((A > B) || (B > A))
```

I don't know how to simplify the last line, if there is any way.

Comment: Just `(B > A)`, the rest was redundant

Comment: Oh my god now I feel stupid. Thank you.

Comment: If this is "pure math" it's off-topic. If it's code, you need to tag it with the correct programming language.

Comment: @Reinderien I believe it’s pure math, but I don’t know what field is this. Maybe it’s computer science?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/